# What is the use of the is_data_sharing field in eav_entity_type?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, eav

I am looking in the Magento database structure and found the `is_data_sharing` field in the table `eav_entity_type`. I want to know what the use of this field is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think for now it does nothing.
Maybe it's the start of a feature that didn't get implemented yet.
I've searched in the code for anything matching `is_data_sharing`, `isDataSharing` and the only places where they show up are

- `is_data_sharing` in the install/upgrade files from the eav module
- `isDataSharing` just in the annotations (getter and setter) in the Entity type model in the eav module.

Answer (score 4):

I have search for **is_data_sharing** column used in magento structure but not find any use of it.

so may be this field used in older version of magento but it's no longer used in magento 1.9 and higher

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about this but `is_data_sharing` term is mostly used for privileges. In DB it maybe related to privileges of attributes Or it maybe use for share attributes between magento stores.